# stylize google map in vue.js project

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

I have a simple [vue project with google maps](https://codesandbox.io/embed/n3y01wlyzm).

Google maps I include using [vue2-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps)

I am trying to make a stylized map like [this shades-of-grey map](https://snazzymaps.com/style/38/shades-of-grey).

So in `options` I use `styles`:

```
export default {
  name: "GoogleMap",
  data() {
    return {
      options: {
        center: {
          lat: 47.376332,
          lng: 8.547511
        },
        zoom: 15,
        styles: [
          {
            featureType: "all",
            elementType: "labels.text.fill",
            styles: [
              {
                saturation: 36
              },
              {
                color: "#000000"
              },
              {
                lightness: 40
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            featureType: "all",
            elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
            stylers: [
              {
                visibility: "on"
              },
              {
                color: "#000000"
              },
              {
                lightness: 16
              }
            ]
          },....
        ]
      }, ...
```

But something wrong. I saw this possibility of connecting styles in other issues on stack & github.

**Question:** How can I stylize google map in vue.js project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the prop name `options` to the `gmap-map` component:

```
<gmap-map id="map" v-bind:options="options" style="width: 100%; height: 500px">
  ...
</gmap-map>
```